# WinML onnx example produce wrong results

Tags: windows-runtime, c++-winrt, windows-machine-learning

I am following this WinML [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/windows-ml/get-started-desktop) to create a regression model and perform inference on it.
I am tried running an onnx model using WinML/WinRT, but the result comes out wrong. I enforced that the data is read as RGB not BGR, but there is an alpha component included, e.g. RGBA, I suspect that the wrong result is due to the alpha, which I do not have it in my original model. How do I come around this problem?
[Code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c57BR.png)
[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbRpj.png)

```
VideoFrame LoadImageFile(hstring filePath, ColorManagementMode colorManagementMode)
{
    BitmapDecoder decoder = NULL;
    try
    {
        // open the file
        StorageFile file = StorageFile::GetFileFromPathAsync(filePath).get();
        // get a stream on it
        auto stream = file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode::Read).get();
        // Create the decoder from the stream
        decoder = BitmapDecoder::CreateAsync(stream).get();
        decoder.GetPixelDataAsync().get().DetachPixelData()[3] = 1;
        decoder.GetPixelDataAsync().get().DetachPixelData()[7] = 1;
        auto pix = decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(BitmapPixelFormat::Rgba8, BitmapAlphaMode::Ignore, BitmapTransform(), ExifOrientationMode::IgnoreExifOrientation, ColorManagementMode::DoNotColorManage);
        for (auto b : pix.get().DetachPixelData())printf("%d\n", b);
       // printf("my pixels: %d", pix.get().DetachPixelData();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        printf("    Failed to load the image file, make sure you are using fully qualified paths\r\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap = NULL;
    try
    {
        softwareBitmap = decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync(
            //decoder.BitmapPixelFormat(),
            BitmapPixelFormat::Rgba8,
            //decoder.BitmapAlphaMode(),
            BitmapAlphaMode::Ignore,
            BitmapTransform(),
            ExifOrientationMode::RespectExifOrientation,
            colorManagementMode
        ).get();
        
        printf("Image format: %d\n", softwareBitmap.BitmapPixelFormat());
    }
```

when I read the pixels from the decoder, I get RGBA, where A (alpha), is set to 255. I tried to replace it with 1, but it appears the that decoder is immutable.
If I can ensure that the pixels fed to model are correct, then this will produce the correct result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Incorrect image format - winRT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64656661/incorrect-image-format-winrt)

Answer (score 1):

Please Just follow the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/windows-ml/get-started-desktop#load-the-image) to create VideoFrame, you don't need to worry about the alpha channel when creating videoFrame because WinML will ignore this channel anyway. And if needed, call [SoftwareBitmap.Convert()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.imaging.softwarebitmap.convert?view=winrt-19041#Windows_Graphics_Imaging_SoftwareBitmap_Convert_Windows_Graphics_Imaging_SoftwareBitmap_Windows_Graphics_Imaging_BitmapPixelFormat_) to convert between different pixel formats

```
VideoFrame LoadImageFile(hstring filePath)
{
    printf("Loading the image...\n");
    DWORD ticks = GetTickCount();
    VideoFrame inputImage = nullptr;

    try
    {
        // open the file
        StorageFile file = StorageFile::GetFileFromPathAsync(filePath).get();
        // get a stream on it
        auto stream = file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode::Read).get();
        // Create the decoder from the stream
        BitmapDecoder decoder = BitmapDecoder::CreateAsync(stream).get();
        // get the bitmap
        SoftwareBitmap softwareBitmap = decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync().get();
        // load a videoframe from it
        inputImage = VideoFrame::CreateWithSoftwareBitmap(softwareBitmap);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        printf("failed to load the image file, make sure you are using fully qualified paths\r\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    ticks = GetTickCount() - ticks;
    printf("image file loaded in %d ticks\n", ticks);
    // all done
    return inputImage;
}
```